# What does the $ means in "$ gem install carrierwave -v "1.0.0"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

It must be very simple, but I can't figure out what this "$" means exactly.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a standard UNIX prompt that appears in a command line terminal for a non-root user. You should not type that character.

Comment: `s/appears/appeared centuries ago/g` nowadays the standard modest prompt in simple theme contains at least 3 lines of 30 characters each :)